# Can't find the mistake, error shown unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery

Can't find the mistake, i just want to change the visibility with the `click`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(#register_link).click(function(){
     $(#signin).animate({visibility:hidden;},"slow");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes:

```
$('#register_link').click(function() {
    $('#signin').animate({visibility:hidden;},"slow");
});
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, you are right, but I tried to use quotes on OP's code , and make minimal changes on it.

Comment: @nnnnnn becuase jquery leads to use `on`. it will be better for him to catch the concetpt now rather than future

Comment: It would be better firstly to use .on('click'), secondly use .fadeOut('slow') I think.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - `.click()` and the other shortcut event methods have not been deprecated (or if they have the current jQuery doco hasn't been updated to say so). Certainly it is better to use `.on()` rather than `.live()` or `.delegate()`, but there's no problem with `.click()`.

Answer (score 1):

you missed `'` quotes for selector

```
$('#register_link').click(function()
{
  $('#signin').animate({visibility:hidden;},"slow");
});
```